# Matrix equation problem

Tags: matrix-equations

Is my solution of this matrix equation correct ?

$(AX^{-1}+B)^{-1}=\frac13X$, I've started off by raising the equation to $-1$ and in the end I get : $((\frac13I-A)^{-1}B)^{-1}$

Comment: Not exactly, it should be 3I instead 1/3*I. Also, you can simplify your solution a bit.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray} 
(AX^{-1}+B)^{-1} & = & \frac{1}{3}X\\
AX^{-1}+B & = & 3X^{-1}\\
B & = & (3I-A)X^{-1}\\
BX & = & (3I-A)\\
X & = & B^{-1}(3I-A)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You need to be a little careful to left multiply and right multiply correctly. It's a right multiply by $X$ in the second last line, and left multiply by $B$ in the last line.